# Will this work for bleeding the brakes

Tags: brakes, diy, bleeding

I'm looking to bleed the brakes but rather than using two people to do it, I did this as a experiment.

[image]

[image]

What I did was bought a 2nd cap for my brake oil and then used a soldering gun to blow a hole through the center, then I cut the end off of the sprayer and pushed it through the cap and used a plastic washer and the soldering gun to melt the 2 plastic pieces together, then I went over it with a hot glue gun, is this a bad idea ?

I'm not sure but I think things like this are pretty expensive for the brake fluid, this costed me 3 dollars for the cap.

Comment: What kind of pressure is your pump capable of? Around 1 bar gauge pressure is good for light duty, some heavy duty trucks require more.

Comment: I'm not sure but it's 170 FL oz/5.0 L with the patent 0660.942

Answer (score 1):

Seems reasonable to give it a shot. I would ensure that there is no chemicals left over in the line or jug.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a cheap version of a commercial one-person brake bleeding kit like this one: https://www.workshopping.co.uk/product/brake--clutch-bleeder/VS1205/

If you get the joints airtight, and it doesn't contaminate the brake fluid, it should work.

Comment: I like that one :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you find clear tubing so you can check for bubbles indicating you could be letting air back into the brake system.

Comment: I got. A bunch of clear tubing but I didn't even think of that, thank you